# Sum with unit steps

Tags: calculus, summation

I have a function

$$F(n,S_T) = n^2 \mathbb{1}_{\frac{1}{n+1}<S_T<\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{1}_{S_T\ge \frac{1}{n}}$$

(where $S_T>0$) and I'm asked to compute the sum

$$F(S_T) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F(n,S_T) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 \mathbb{1}_{\frac{1}{n+1}<S_T<\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{1}_{S_T\ge \frac{1}{n}}$$

Can you help me to solve it? By eye it seems to diverge (at least the first term) but I'm not completely sure. Thanks.

Comment: The sum in the first term involves only $n$ with $n <\frac 1 {S_T}$. So it is a finite sum.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what about splitting the first sum by splitting the unity?

Comment: Is $S_T$ an indicator function?

Comment: @Alex no, it is a positive (random) variable (in particular it represents a price)

Comment: In fact, that first part of the sum has (at most) one term in it since $\frac{1}{n+1}<S_r<\frac{1}{n}$ means $\frac{1}{S_r}-1<n<\frac{1}{S_r}$, and there can be at most one integer in an open interval of length 1.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ok but then how do I compute the sum? I don’t know which integer there is (if there is one) in the interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $\frac{1}{n+1}<S_T<\frac{1}{n}$ can be rearranged to $\frac{1}{S_T}-1<n<\frac{1}{S_T}$. Assuming that $\frac{1}{S_T}$ is not itself an integer, then $k=\lfloor\frac{1}{S_r}\rfloor$ is the only integer in this interval.

The sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 \mathbb{1}_{\frac{1}{n+1}<S_T<\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{1}_{S_T\ge \frac{1}{n}}$$
can then be written as
$$k^2 + \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Given the well known infinite sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

your sum becomes the finite sum
$$k^2 + \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = k^2 + \frac{\pi^2}{6} -  \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n^2} $$

If $\frac{1}{S_T}$ is an integer then you get the same without the first $k^2$ term, and the sum goes up to $k-1$.

Comment: I know that it is strange, but is there any possibility to get a result which depends on $S_T$? Because the next step of the exercise asks to compute the derivative with respect to $S_T$... maybe it is a trivial question and the answer is just 0 but I don't think so

Comment: @shot22 Yes, the derivative is zero. The summation result changes step-wise at certain values of $S_T$, but is constant in-between.